# Trim a string with Regex

Tags: php, regex

I have these strings:

```
Sexy too! -----Original Message----- From: djsgsgjdigjdisgjdigjdis Sent: Tuesday, 09    September 2

heyp -----Original Message----- From: rejgisdgifdogdsgdsgds Sent: Tuesday, 09 September 2

Sexy too! -----Original Message----- From: fdkfdgkifdjgfidsjgidjgdsgdgs Sent: Tuesday, 09 September 2
```

But I want to crop them after the `-----Original Message-----` bit so they're just simple words (heyp, sexy too!, etc)?

I tried using str_replace, but it didn't work.

How can I do this using preg_replace in PHP?

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried and expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are dealing with a literal substring the faster way is to use explode:

```
$result = explode(' -----Original Message----- ', $line, 2)[0]; // PHP >= 5.4
```

or for older PHP versions:

```
list($result,) =  explode(' -----Original Message----- ', $line, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `preg_replace`, but you don't need to. Consider using [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) instead.

```
$separatorIndex = strpos($originalMessage, '-----Original Message-----');
if ($separatorIndex !== false) {
    $originalMessage = substr($originalMessage, 0, $separatorIndex);
}

echo $originalMessage;
```

Answer (score 0):

The below will provide you with matches in the `$matches` variable parsed from in-front of the `-` part of the string.

```
$re = "/(?:(.*)\\s+-+.*)/"; 
$str = "Sexy too! -----Original Message----- From: djsgsgjdigjdisgjdigjdis Sent: Tuesday, 09    September 2\n\nheyp -----Original Message----- From: rejgisdgifdogdsgdsgds Sent: Tuesday, 09 September 2\n\nSexy too! -----Original Message----- From: fdkfdgkifdjgfidsjgidjgdsgdgs Sent: Tuesday, 09 September 2"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `preg_replace` like this.

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s*-----Original Message-----.*/', '', $string);
```

Or you could use `substr`:

```
$string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, ' -----Original Message-----'));
```